# Automated Postman Tests on github Actions fails with ECONNREFUSED

Tags: postman, github-actions

Im trying to setup a workflow on a Pull request.
The jobs are:

- Setup a MySQL database
- Build and Test a NetCore API
- Run automated Postman Tests

The yml file looks like this:

```
name: .NET Core, MySQL and Postman

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master, dev ]

jobs:
  test_and_build_API:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Setup MySQL
    - uses: mirromutth/mysql-action@v1.1
      with:
        collation server: 'utf8_general_ci' # Optional, default value is 'utf8mb4_general_ci'. The '--collation-server' option for mysqld
        mysql version: '8.0' # Optional, default value is "latest". The version of the MySQL
        mysql database: 'FantasyFestivals' # Optional, default value is "test". The specified database which will be create
        mysql root password: 'root' # Required if "mysql user" is empty, default is empty. The root superuser password:

    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Setup .NET Core
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
      with:
        dotnet-version: 3.1.101
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: dotnet restore
    - name: Build
      run: dotnet build --configuration Release --no-restore
    - name: Test_Postman
      uses: matt-ball/newman-action@master
      with:
        collection: Postman/MedievalFestivals - Medieval Festivals RestAPI.postman_collection.json
        environment: Postman/FantasyFestivals Tesing.postman_environment.json
    - name: Test
      run: dotnet test --no-restore --verbosity normal
```

**Error**
The Workflow fails on step 3 when running the automated postman tests with newman.

```
MedievalFestivals - Medieval Festivals RestAPI

❏ api/festivals
↳ Get Festivals
  1⠄ TypeError in prerequest-script
  GET https://localhost:5001/api/festivals?PageSize=45 [errored]
     connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5001
  3⠄ JSONError in test-script
_tls_wrap.js:549
  self._destroySSL();
```

Questions:

- (THIS HAS BEEN ANSWERED IN THE COMMENTS) Do the built containers within each job dissapear (get cleaned up) after the job has finished? So when the job "test_and_build" starts the MySQL database is not accessible by this job anymore? If so, do I have to put the steps of each job inside one single job?
- How do I resolve the ECONNREFUSED Error?

Thanks for you help.
Virtual potato:

Comment: Yes, separating the jobs as you have done means that your database and API are no longer available. Dependencies need to exist within the same job.

Comment: That helps thank you. Now hopefully a hero can answer the second question :)

Comment: It looks like you're not running your code (No `dotnet run`)? What does your API return when queried with curl or something similar?

Comment: The API works fine with Postman. When I manually send out the requests. You may be right that I just have to dotnet run in the yml script. thanks for the advice

Comment: My question was about using curl or something similar in the CI to determine if the problem is your newman configuration or something else (like not having the API server running at all).